# Proving x >= a /\ x <= a -> x = a

Tags: coq, inequalities

How would one go about proving the following

```
Theorem T: forall x, a: nat, x >= a /\ x <= a -> x = a.
```

in Coq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the full power of `omega`, I would search the standard library for the antisymmetric property of `<=` using `SearchPattern` or `SearchAbout` (or google) and `apply le_antisym`.

If you want a proof without using lemmas from the library, go by induction on `x` and `a`.